# C# Entity Framework query using boolean expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm very new to Entity, and I'm trying to find all elements in a DbSet object that match a boolean condition that's passed as a string:

```
Example: 
string condition = "Weight > 30 && Age == 20";
var results = context.Data.FindIf(condition);
```

where Weight and Age are properties of Data, and the boolean condition given can vary. I can hard code it easily with LINQ expressions but is there a way to do it in the way I described?

Comment: Take a look to a code sample called Dynamic LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DynamicLinqQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) library to use string epxressions against the IQueryable sources. The library is built on top of feature described in MSDN article of Expression tree and dynamic query builders shared by @tdbeckett

It allows you to write dynamic conditions as string e.g.

`using System.Linq.Dynamic;`

`var query =
    db.Customers.
    Where("City = @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10);`

There's a Nuget package available for this:

> Install-Package [DynamicQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicQuery/)

One you finish installation you can find an HTML file added in the project for help documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, worked like a charm! For future reference to anyone else, I used `var results = db.Data.Where(queryRequest);` where `queryRequest` is a string containing a boolean expression.

Answer (score 5):

Expression trees can do want you want here.  You can parse the string to build the expression tree.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [raw SQL query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) and just execute normal SQL against it?

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<Data>("SELECT * FROM [DataTable] WHERE Weight > 30 AND Age = 20");
```

Comment: The boolean string condition is passed to me and I have to process that, I can't use a SQL query unless I construct one from that string.

Comment: you can use expression trees

Comment: Is that condition guaranteed to be a valid LINQ query or do you have to validate it anyway?  If you have to mess with it anyway, then this answer is an easy to understand candidate IMO, but if you know it'll be valid LINQ, I recommend @tdbeckett's answer.